# Установка Selenoid

Tags: windows

При попытке установить Selenoid и вводе команды "sudo wget [https://github.com/aerokube/cm/releases/download/1.5.7/cm_linux_amd64"](https://github.com/aerokube/cm/releases/download/1.5.7/cm_linux_amd64%22)
пишет соответственно:
" "sudo" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом."
Как фиксить?

Comment: sudo - это под линуксы, в винде не работает

Comment: И бинарник ты качаешь не под винду, если чё.

Comment: Или поставить wget или пользоваться штатными средствами того же пошика.